# How to skip some of the entity from ddl update

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

have several `javax.persistence.Entity`

most of them are created for the current module, so keeping
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update`

Since some of the tables are already there. I was wondering how can I skip updating the DDL for a few of the already existing entities.

also, I am okay letting the application fail on runtime but have a corrupted table.

Comment: I would highly recommend the usage of a dedicated database migration tool like [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) or [liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Like advised in the comment it is a situation where a migration tool like fylway/liquibase would be most helpful.

https://www.baeldung.com/database-migrations-with-flyway

By specifying (like shown in the guide) `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...` your tables will only be created if they don't exist already which is exactly what you wanted